# How to reply to an Outlook mailitem using .net

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, office-interop, office-2007

I am writing an Outlook 2007 Add-in which composes a business quote in response to an email query. I compose the quote using Windows forms. Everything works fine until I get to the point of replying to the original message with the quote information.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Outlook.MailItem theMail = ((Outlook._MailItem)quote.mailItem).Reply();
    theMail.Subject = "This is the quote";
    theMail.Body = &lt;Some html composed elsewhere&gt;;

    Outlook.Recipient rcp = theMail.Recipients.Add("Joe Blow");
    Outlook.AddressEntry ae = rcp.AddressEntry;
    ae.Address = "joe@blow.com";
}
```

Where `quote.mailItem` is the incoming email request. When I run the code, it throws an exception executing `rcp.AddressEntry`. The error is

> 'An object cannot be found'

.
What I need to be able to do is add and delete addressees as well as setting *CC* and *BCC* fields on the quote before I send it out. Addressees may not be in the address book. I have done this with other mail libraries and it should be simple, but I seem to be barking up the wrong tree for Outlook.

EDIT Found it - thanks Dmitry for pointing me in the right direction.

```
Outlook.Recipient rcp = theMail.Recipients.Add("joe blow <joe@blow.com>");
rcp.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
```

Comment: If the answer of dimitry is correct, please rate and accept it :)

Comment: The problem was not address resolution as provided in Dmitry's answer, but he did get me into the proper area of the documentation for which I thanked him.

Answer (score 1):

The recipient must be resolved first . And you cannot set the AddressEntry.Address property - even if it were settable, it does not point back to the message recipients table.

```
Outlook.Recipient rcp = theMail.Recipients.Add("Joe Blow <joe@blow.com>");
rcp.Resolve();
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - am I to infer that a recipient must be in the address book before Outlook will send mail to him?

Comment: No, "Joe Blow <joe@blow.com>" will be resolved to a one-off SMTP recipient. This is not any different from manually typing the address in the To edit box in Outlook and hitting Ctrl+K to resolve it.